# How to make video unaccessible outside the HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to create a video streaming application. In this application, the users will be able to upload their video, which will be stored in AWS S3. When some other authorized user (followers) wants to access this video,I generate a presigned URL for the object and use this URL in the video source in HTML. It works fine, but the issue is, the users will be able to access the video link from the HTML code (if they do an inspect). They can share this link with other unauthorized people. I don't want them to be able to access the video directly using the link.

How do I implement this?

Alternative approach - is there a way to disable "inspect" and also "save file as" ?

Comment: It is impossible to prevent someone from this.  Best you can do is DRM.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that there is no way to hide or disable the "inspect" mechanism, according to the nature of web applications.

But about your main question, There is some ways to prevent access to files (specially videos). The most popular one is to generate and send `secret_key` with your file url. Your secret_key is depends on different parameters related to authorization. When you want to serve the video (or streams), you should check the secret_key with the Content-Type header to ensure that this request is from your website not another client.

I think services like Wowza, Mux and Agora have this feature to reduce your back-end pains.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above.  Yes, Wowza, Mux, etc all have signed playback URLs.  These can have different ways to authenticate-- have an expiration date, tie it to an IP address, Referrer etc